# What is the data type for Facebook's third_party_id?

Tags: sql, sql-server, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to use Facebook's third party id as an index in sql.

It is obviously some type of string, however I am not sure if I should expect it to always be a certain or at least maximum length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the third_party_id is around 28 characters but I wouldn't rely on this: if Facebook didn't release more information about it it's because they want to have the ability to change it (let's say in case a third party was able to regenerate the Facebook Id from the third_party_id). I would just use a nvarchar(50).

Answer (score 0):

I always use long int(16) in mysql... it works, but don't think, that is good solution ;- ) And Facebook ID hasn't always the same length, e.g. '1399156453', '100000459881034'.

Comment: I am not asking about facebook's User ID. They have another user property called a third_party_id. Facebook's UID type is a bigint (at least in SqlServer).

Answer (score 0):

From [Facebook Reference](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) It's an anonymous, but unique identifier for the user; only returned if specifically requested via the fields URL parameter,which return in **String** Format and this `Requires access_token`

Comment: As I said in my question, it is obviously a string. I was looking for something more specific that would allow me to set it as an index in a sql database. Specifically a length.

Comment: Just make it a VARCHAR(100) or something, that should do. And when creating the index, use the same amount of characters there.